# Run catkin make with custom compiler

Tags: catkin-make, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried exporting the `CC`, `CXX`, `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` env variables before running `./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install`, but no luck. It still insists on using clang on OS X (10.8.2) for some reason. How can I tell it to use gcc instead?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56398/run-catkin-make-with-custom-compiler/) by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2013-02-26

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-02-27**:
Just curious - is this to get around the bug in clang that prevents PCL from building?

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-27**:
@Dan Lazewatsky: Indeed it is. I'm thinking building the whole thing with the gcc kit (or at least PCL and friends) will be the easy way!

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-02-27**:
Awesome. I'm excited to see how it work out!

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-27**:
Sure, will let you know. ;)

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-27**:
@Dan Lazewatsky: Okay, there seems to be problems with the generators! They're returnin HTTP 500 errors now (desktop and desktop-full rather).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can pass them in as CMake variables:

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -v
```

This should make each of the run with the C/CXX compiler changed:

```
==> cmake /Users/william/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/william/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/william/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.2.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.2.1
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-28**:
This works if I pass the parameters to cmake directly, but not catkin_make_isolated unfortunately! Catkin is really causing a lot of trouble, I have no idea what it's good for even... surely a build script that just loops through each directory in src/ and runs CMake would be superior as a solution?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-02-28**:
That's what catkin_make_isolated does... There is no reason (other than maybe a bug) for why passing CMake arguments to CMake directly would work but not for CMI...

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-02-28**:
It's pretty clear exactly which commands CMI is running, and if one fails it even tells you exactly how to reproduce that error without CMI. You can always build pcl_msgs manually, install it, build pcl manually, install it, remove them from the workspace, then try again.

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-28**:
@William: Ah, well it seems that it works okay if I set environment variables, but whenever I pass the D options it always fails in the infinite loop (either directly via cmake or via catkin_make_isolated).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the most easy way to change the compiler CMake uses, is by adding the following to the respective CMakeList.txt file:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "clang++")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "clang")
```

---

Originally posted by [stefanct](https://answers.ros.org/users/14656/stefanct/) with karma: 41 on 2014-04-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [li9i](https://answers.ros.org/users/12651/li9i/) on 2019-09-26**:
Actually the path to the executable should be absolute:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang++")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang")
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried using a toolchain.cmake file?

Here is an example (for cross-compiling to the raspberry pi), I set the arm cross compiler:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.4)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH $ENV{HOME}/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/sysroot $ENV{HOME}/rpi/rootfs $ENV{HOME}/rpi/rootfs/e2fsprogs-1.42.9 $ENV{HOME}/rpi/rootfs/usr $ENV{HOME}/rpi/rootfs/usr/lib $ENV{HOME}/rpi/rootfs/usr/include $ENV{HOME}/rpi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated)
#SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=softfp -mcpu=arm1176jzf-s" )
#SET( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -static" )
# Have to set this one to BOTH, to allow CMake to find python
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

Then, I invoke it with:

```
catkin_make_isolated --cmake-args -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/myuser/rpi/toolchain.raspi.cmake
```

---

Originally posted by [ceverett](https://answers.ros.org/users/1761/ceverett/) with karma: 332 on 2014-04-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [strike_eagle_iii](https://answers.ros.org/users/38642/strike_eagle_iii/) on 2018-11-20**:
This should be the correct answer.  Using a toolchain file is the canonical way to do this with cmake.